# Sqlite Autoincrement

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to update the id column in a table of memos. So if a memo with the id of 3 gets deleted, the row underneath now becomes id of 3.

```
sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
            "ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, MEMO TEXT, URGENCY TEXT)");
```

to create the table, works perfectly fine but i'm getting a sqlite error "near autoincrement".

```
 db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " AUTOINCREMENT = 
                      (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM " + TABLE_NAME + ");");
```

Comment: AUTOINCREMENT means that when you add new row in the column the ID will automaticaly increase by 1, so you do not need to pay attention to this column. And it will not decrease when you delete the row, the next row you add will be still greater by 1 than the previous (even deleted) row.

Answer (score 2):

`AUTOINCREMENT` does not work as I guess you are expecting.

If a column has the type `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` then a slightly different `ROWID` selection algorithm is used. The `ROWID` chosen for the new row is at least **one larger than the largest ROWID that has ever before existed** in that same table.